# multiline using fancy footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

A simple question. Multiline in footer.
centered and leftmost text is ok, but i am not able to do righ footer multine. The first line always go to the center.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%definir a fonte a utilizar
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\rfoot{test \newline test}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to substitute `\newline` with `\\` (see [`fancyhdr` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf), section 11), thus the line

```
\rfoot{test \newline test}
```

must be

```
\rfoot{test \\ test}
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%definir a fonte a utilizar
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\rfoot{test \\ test}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

Output

> [image]